# AngularJS - placeholder for empty result from filter

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to have a place holder, e.g. `<No result>` when filter result returns empty. Could anyone please help? I don't even know where to start...

**HTML**:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
<h1>My Foo</h1>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="foo in foos">
        <a href="#" ng-click="setBarFilter(foo.name)">{{foo.name}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<br />
<h1>My Bar</h1>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="bar in bars | filter:barFilter">{{bar.name}}</li>
</ul>

</div>
```

**JS**:

```
function Ctrl($scope) {

  $scope.foos = [{
    name: 'Foo 1'
  },{
    name: 'Foo 2'
  },{
    name: 'Foo 3'
  }];

  $scope.bars = [{
    name: 'Bar 1',
    foo: 'Foo 1'
  },{
    name: 'Bar 2',
    foo: 'Foo 2'
  }];

  $scope.setBarFilter = function(foo_name) {
    $scope.barFilter = {};
    $scope.barFilter.foo = foo_name;
  }
}
```

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/adrn/PEumV/1/

Thanks!

Comment: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/angular/wR06cN5oVBQ/decEAdq3n30J

Comment: ah yeah nice trick with ng-show. Thanks very much

Answer (score 252, accepted):

A tweak on the approach that only requires you to specify the filter once:

```
  <li ng-repeat="bar in filteredBars = (bars | filter:barFilter)">{{bar.name}}</li>
</ul>
<p ng-hide="filteredBars.length">Nothing here!</p>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/k4u5z/)

Comment: This is the nicer solution in that you only need to declare your filter once. +1

Comment: The problem is that the "Nothing here!" part is shown and hidden really quickly. When you get data with an ajax request there is an delay before the returned data is shown and in that time you can see the "Nothing here!" part appear and disappear.

Comment: @Temega - you could add a class "ng-hide" to the div

Comment: @Temega You could use ng-show="filteredBars.length === 0"

Comment: I use ng-controller="FooController as $ctrl" and did "bar in $ctrl.filteredBars = (bars | filter:barFilter)" so I could even use $ctrl.filteredBars.length outside the ng-repeat. Thanks for this epic hint!

Answer (score 37):

Here is the trick using ng-show

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
<h1>My Foo</h1>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="foo in foos">
        <a href="#" ng-click="setBarFilter(foo.name)">{{foo.name}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<br />
<h1>My Bar</h1>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="bar in bars | filter:barFilter">{{bar.name}}</li>
</ul>
<p ng-show="(bars | filter:barFilter).length == 0">Nothing here!</p>

</div>
```

**jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/adrn/PEumV/2/

Comment: But in this case the filter is executed twice, is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I have been using the groupBy filter provided here https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter but unfortunately the accepted answer above does not work. This method may execute the filter twice but it solved the problem regardless.

Comment: In my case it works without the "== 0". <p ng-show="(bars | filter:barFilter).length">Nothing here!</p>

Answer (score 21):

Taken from [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#animations) official document that's how they do it:

```
ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:q as results"
```

Then use the results as an array

```
<li class="animate-repeat" ng-if="results.length == 0">
  <strong>No results found...</strong>
</li>
```

Full snippet:

```
<div ng-controller="repeatController">
I have {{friends.length}} friends. They are:
<input type="search" ng-model="q" placeholder="filter friends..." aria-label="filter friends" />


<ul class="example-animate-container">
    <li class="animate-repeat" ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:q as results">
      [{{$index + 1}}] {{friend.name}} who is {{friend.age}} years old.
    </li>
    <li class="animate-repeat" ng-if="results.length == 0">
      <strong>No results found...</strong>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I suspect things changed since this question was first asked, but given that currently this is exactly how Angular's docs suggest you solve the problem, I would say this is the right way to go at this point.

Comment: I couldn't find another example. This is "hidden", in their animation documentation and it was by chance that I noticed it on the same day i needed it or I don't think i would have remembered.