# Hiding parent div if filter renders child div empty in Angular

Tags: angularjs, filter, ng-show

I found this answer: [AngularJS - hide parent element if children loop is empty (filtered)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17652665/angularjs-hide-parent-element-if-children-loop-is-empty-filtered) but it didn't seem to work for me.

My code, which works perfectly, is:

```
    <div ng-repeat="lawyer in articlesByAuthor | orderObjectBy:'lastname':false" ng-show="sortType=='author'">
    <h3>{{lawyer.fullname}}</h3>
    <br/>
        <table border="1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="padding: 2px 5px;">
                    Date Published 
                    </th>
                    <th style="padding: 2px 5px;">
                    Article
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="article in lawyer | filter:searchArticle">
                    <td style="padding: 2px 5px;white-space:nowrap;">
                    {{article.date | date:'MMM. dd, yyyy'}}
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding: 2px 5px;;">
                    <a href="{{article.link}}" target="_blank" ng-if="article.link != ''"><span ng-bind-html="renderHtml(article.title)" class="articlePage"></span></a><span ng-bind-html="renderHtml(article.title)" class="articlePage" ng-if="article.link == ''"></span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <br/><br/>
    </div>
```

but, if the search renders such that no articles show up, I'm still stuck looking at an empty table with the name over it.

Based on the above, I tried wrapping the whole thing in:

```
<div ng-show="(lawyer | filter:searchArticle).length">
</div>
```

to no avail. It doesn't show no matter what. I've replaced `lawyer` with `article` and `articlesByAuthor` and neither work.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The code was right. I was just putting it in the wrong place. I needed to put the conditional ng-show just INSIDE the first ng-repeat.