# Ionic angular nested ng-repeat filter, hide title if empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a nested list with a filter , it has days and activities.

objects looks like :

```
days:[ 
{name:"monday", acts[{title:"Zumba",start:"10am",end:"11am"},{}..]}...
]
```

Filter works good but I'd like to hide the day header (group.title) when filter returns 0 activities for that day.

I found some answers like this : [AngularJS - hide parent element if children loop is empty (filtered)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17652665/angularjs-hide-parent-element-if-children-loop-is-empty-filtered)

And tried to implement with no success.

This is my code :

view

```
<ion-view view-title="{{titulo}}">
  <ion-content>
      <div class="container-hearder-image" style="background-image: url('{{img}}');" >
    </div>
    <h4>{{titulo}}</h4>
    <p>Seleccione Actividades</p>
      <div ng-repeat="c in colors">
          <ion-checkbox ng-click="includeColour(c)" class="item-bcg waves-effect waves-block waves-light"/> {{c}}
       </div>
    <ion-list ng-repeat="group in detailService.selected.days" >
        <div class="item item-divider bar bar-header bar-calm" >{{group.title}}</div>
        <ion-list ng-repeat="item in group.acts | filter:colourFilter">
          <ion-item >
            <h3>{{item.title}}</h3>
            {{item.start}} - {{item.end}}
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>      
    </ion-list> 
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

controller

```
.controller('HorarioCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams,detailService) {


    $scope.colors = ['Zumba','Combat','Spinning','HIIT','Pilates','Yoga'];
    $selected = detailService.selected
    $scope.detailService=detailService;
    $scope.titulo = detailService.selected.title;
    $scope.img = detailService.selected.img;
    colourIncludes = [];
    $scope.colourIncludes = colourIncludes

    $scope.includeColour = function(colour) {
        var i = $.inArray(colour, colourIncludes);
        if (i > -1) {
            colourIncludes.splice(i, 1);
        } else {
            colourIncludes.push(colour);
        }
    }

    $scope.colourFilter = function(fruit) {
        if (colourIncludes.length > 0) {
            if ($.inArray(fruit.title, colourIncludes) < 0)
                return;
        }

        return fruit;
    }
});
```

Regards

Comment: Do you have everything else set correctly? Is the output of your ng-repeat as you would expect?

Comment: Please tell me what is the data  in `group.title`, `item.title`, `item.start` and `item.end`

Comment: @ThomasJuranek yes, data is filtering properly , but for example if I check "Yoga" and its present on monday only , output looks like this : 

Monday
Yoga
Thursday
Wednesday
Tuesday
Friday
Saturday

I like to show :

Monday 
Yoga

Comment: @CharanCherry group.title = is the name of the day, item title is the name of the activity, item start is the time its starting and end is the time its ending, let me show you a screenshot of my output :  https://i.gyazo.com/bf4dc7b1630d588a2fe3b1539b234401.png all titles without activities filtered must hide

Comment: I have edited my answer below. Try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use alias expression which will then store the intermediate results of the repeater after the filters have been applied.

```
<div class="item item-divider bar bar-header bar-calm" ng-if="filteredElements.length>0">{{group.title}}</div>
<ion-list ng-repeat="item in group.acts | filter:colourFilter as filteredElements">
 <ion-item >
   <h3>{{item.title}}</h3>
    {{item.start}} - {{item.end}}
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: Works! , I was days trying to get to something like this. Thank you very much !!

Answer (score 1):

As the other post you linked above answered, ngShow would work in this scenario.

```
<h3 ng-show="item.title != null">{{item.title}}</h3>
```

Comment: it doesnt work .. I tried with many ng-show combinations but seems like the solution its not in that way. Title with no activities still showing

Answer (score 1):

If group.acts.length greater than zero, show the title. Else, display none

```
 <ion-list ng-repeat="group in detailService.selected.days" >
        <div ng-if="colourFilter.length>0" class="item item-divider bar bar-header bar-calm" >{{group.title}}</div>
        <ion-list ng-repeat="item in group.acts | filter:colourFilter">
          <ion-item >
            <h3>{{item.title}}</h3>
            {{item.start}} - {{item.end}}
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>      
    </ion-list>
```

Comment: Doesnt work. Seems like as I'm using filters group.acts.length does not change to 0 when filtering.

Comment: It should work because `acts` is the array of activities. So, if there are any activities, the array length will be greater than zero. Title only appears if acts.length greater than zero. Please check console if anything wrong.