# angular js ng-repeat:filter return size

Tags: angularjs

I'm using ng-repeat with filter:search and I want to know when you try and filter and it returns nothing so I can search the rest of the records not just the records of the ng-repeat.

Example

ng-repeat="s in tbl | filter: search"

tbl is length 125(i found this to be around the most for a table to run smoothly) and lets say i have a total of 1000 records that i use pagination to change to. If the search filter returns 0 I want to be able to search the rest of those records but I need to be able to know when the search returns nothing.

[image: Filtered by sort by group and update schedule. total of 4 possibilities]

Comment: Try this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14615495/angularjs-placeholder-for-empty-result-from-filter#answer-14656659

Comment: tbl should contain 1000 records and since you could you limitTo to implement the pagination, the filter will be applied to the entire list rather than the 1 page.

Comment: i get the ng-show to work but I need to recognize this on the controller side. The 1000 records is already being filter also. I could do this I would have to change up the records into multiple arrays though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write a custom filter. And do something similar to this.

```
.filter('filterFunction', function() {

  return function (objects) {

    var filtered_list = [];

    var filterFunction = function(array) {
      for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (something) filtered_list.push(array[i]);
      }
    }

    filterFunction(objects);
    while (filtered_list.length === 0) {
      objects = ... get new list ...
      filterFunction(objects);
    }

    return filtered_list;

  }
});
```

Comment: This makes the most sense especially since i'll use this in multiple projects. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It's best to keep your display logic out of your controller.

So to keep track of your results put something like this in your HTML

```
{{(tbl | filter:search).length}}
```

So if you were to implement that it would look like:

```
<div>
  <tablestuff></tablestuff>
  {{(tbl | filter:search).length}}
</div>
```

That will dynamically show the length of the filtered results.

Comment: Exactly the solution i was looking for. Perfect.