# AngularJS: placeholder for empty results appearing on page load

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working with an Angular table and I want to display a message only if the user's filters do not match any results.

Here is my method (taken from [this helpful thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14615495/angularjs-placeholder-for-empty-result-from-filter))

**ng-repeat**

```
<tr ng-repeat-start="item in t.filteredList = (t.data | dynamicFilter:t.filter:t.order)">
```

**"no results" block**

```
<tr class="no-results" ng-show="!t.filteredList.length" ng-cloak>
```

The problem is that when the page loads, after ng-cloak has been overridden, `ng-show` reads the length of `filteredList` as 0 which leads to this "no results" block flashing on the screen and then disappearing.

Any thoughts on how to hide this block as the page loads?

Comment: how about using something like an additional "isInitialized"-property on your controller and set it to true after everything has loaded?

Comment: That's a good idea, I just can't seem to get anything in the controller to detect when the filter has finished executing. I even tried declaring `t.filteredList = ['placeholder']` so that the array had a length before the filter executed, but `ng-show` kept reading the array length as 0 while the page was loading.

Comment: What about add the condition for ng-show, to also check t.data exist?

Comment: YES!! Thank you. That 100% worked. Final code: `<tr class="no-results" ng-show="!t.filteredList.length && t.data" ng-cloak>`