# AngularJS - Count results after using both filter and groupBy

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

I am using angular with [angular-filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter)

Filtering and grouping is working. But I also want to check if the filtered list is empty, similar to this question:
[AngularJS - placeholder for empty result from filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14615495/angularjs-placeholder-for-empty-result-from-filter)

In the sample below I use `player in filteredPlayers = (players | filter:search)` to access the count through `filteredPlayers.length`

How can I do something similar for the grouped list in the example?

Code:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['angular.filter']);
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.players = [
  {name: 'Gene', team: 'alpha'},
  {name: 'George', team: 'beta'},
  {name: 'Steve', team: 'gamma'},
  {name: 'Paula', team: 'beta'},
  {name: 'Scruath', team: 'gamma'}
];
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.8/angular-filter.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="search">
    <hr>
    <div ng-hide="filteredPlayers.length">
      This list is empty. (this is working).
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="player in filteredPlayers = (players | filter:search)">
        player: {{ player.name }}
      </li>
    </ul>
    <hr>
    <div>
      The list is empty. (this is not working - always displayed).
    </div>
    <ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in players | filter:search | groupBy: 'team'">
      Group name: {{ key }}
      <li ng-repeat="player in value">
        player: {{ player.name }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `value.length`? Or you mean for all filtered players?

Comment: I want the number of items for the whole collection, not for each group.

Comment: Then you can do just the same right?: `(key, value) in filteredPlayers = (players | filter:search) | groupBy: 'team'`

Comment: Then it seems filteredPlayers will be an object with 'alpha' and 'beta' properties, nothing I can check the length of directly. But thanks - maybe I can count the properties of the object to determine if there are any groupings. If there is a cleaner/simpler way count the results I'd prefer that, though. Maybe some way of assigning a variable before the grouping happen?

Comment: Yes. I juggled a bit, and it works: `(key, value) in (filteredPlayers = (players | filter:search) | groupBy: 'team')`

Comment: I was misunderstanding how to assign values inside the filter/grouping part. Your suggestion made me figure it out. Thanks! Answer it if you would like me to accept it as an answer, or I'll answer it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something similar:

```
<ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in (filteredPlayers = (players | filter:search) | groupBy: 'team')">
    ..
</ul>

<h1>Length: {{ filteredPlayers.length }}</h1>
```