# Filter does not show a message instead of a table if the filtering returns empty result

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, html-table

Having a table with data on it and a selector which must filter the data based on a selection made in a selector, I want to show a message ("No data") if the filtering returns no data.

The selector looks like this:

```
<select ng-model="$ctrl.type">
    <option value="">All</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
```

table is generated here:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="rows in $ctrl.myData | filter: {Type: $ctrl.type} track by $index">
        <td>
            <span>{{rows.Type}}</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span>...</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

myData is an array of objects like:

```
myData = [
        {Type: "1", SiteId: 8, SiteName: "aaa"},
        {Type: "1", SiteId: 7, SiteName: "asb"},
        {Type: "2", SiteId: 1, SiteName: "aaa"},
        {Type: "1", SiteId: 17, SiteName: "x"},
        {Type: "2", SiteId: 7, SiteName: "xx"}
];
```

It works fine as it is now but when I select `3` it shows the table headers and no data. I want to show a message in this case instead of the table headers.

I tried to wrap around the `ng-repeat` with an `ng-if` like this:

```
<tbody>
    <div ng-if="$ctrl.myData.filter(s => s.Type == $ctrl.type).length > 0"> 
        <tr ng-repeat=...>
            ...
        </tr>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="$ctrl.myData.filter(s => s.Type == $ctrl.type).length == 0"> 
        NO DATA FOR THIS OPTION
    </div>
</tbody>
```

but it has no effect on it.

Any suggestions about how to show a message if the selected `Type` has no data?

Comment: possible duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14615495/angularjs-placeholder-for-empty-result-from-filter

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Comment: not yet, trying to figure out if that question can solve my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try: `"rows in $ctrl.myData | filter: {Type: $ctrl.type} as filtered track by $index "`
and under your table  `<div ng-if="!filtered.length">No results</div>`
https://plnkr.co/edit/diNlE0lS8eFttvgBUHug?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14656659/4281154) you can update your code as follow. I hope it will fix your problem

```
<tbody>
         <tr ng-repeat="rows in filteredData = ($ctrl.myData | filter: {Type: $ctrl.type} track by $index">
            <td>
                <span>{{rows.Type}}</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span>...</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <div ng-hide="filteredData.length"> 
            NO DATA FOR THIS OPTION
        </div>
    </tbody>
```